# Typescript js.map files loaded by the browser using a wrong path

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't understand why my browser is trying to load my `js.map` files using a wrong path.

Here is what I have in my `<head>` HTML part:

Here is what it tries to load:

[image]

What's wrong is that it tries to load the file inside the folder `assets`, which doesn't exist. The right path would be `scripts/widget/Spinner.ts`.

I can access the files directly using the right path and it works (by the URL), also, the JS files are correctly loaded.

So I guess the `.js.map` files references somehow the wrong path for the related TS (I don't know exactly how it works behind the scene).

Here is the `Spinner.js.map` file's content:

```
{"version":3,"file":"Spinner.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../../assets/scripts/widget/Spinner.ts"],"names":["Payline","Payline.Spinner","Payline.Spinner.constructor","Payline.Spinner.spin","Payline.Spinner.getSpinnerLibrary","Payline.Spinner.autorun","Payline.Spinner.hide","Payline.Spinner.show"],"mappings":"AAAA,kDAAkD;AAElD,IAAO,OAAO,CAiLb;AAjLD,WAAO,OAAO,EAAC,CAAC;IAaZA,AAXAA;;;;;;;;;;OAUGA;QACUA,OAAOA;QAsDhBC;;;;;;;WAOGA;QACHA,SA9DSA,OAAOA,CA8DJA,OAAiBA,EAAEA,MAAYA,EAAEA,MAAyBA;YAA1DC,uBAAiBA,GAAjBA,YAAiBA;YAAgBA,sBAAyBA,GAAzBA,iBAAyBA;YAxCtEA;;eAEGA;YACKA,gBAAWA,GAAGA,MAAMA,CAACA,SAASA,CAACA,CAACA;YAOxCA;;eAEGA;YACKA,oBAAeA,GAAQA;gBAC3BA,KAAKA,EAAEA,EAAEA;gBACTA,MAAMA,EAAEA,EAAEA;gBACVA,KAAKA,EAAEA,EAAEA;gBACTA,MAAMA,EAAEA,EAAEA;gBACVA,OAAOA,EAAEA,CAACA;gBACVA,MAAMA,EAAEA,CAACA;gBACTA,SAASA,EAAEA,CAACA;gBACZA,KAAKA,EAAEA,MAAMA;gBACbA,KAAKA,EAAEA,CAACA;gBACRA,KAAKA,EAAEA,EAAEA;gBACTA,MAAMA,EAAEA,KAAKA;gBACbA,OAAOA,EAAEA,KAAKA;gBACdA,SAASA,EAAEA,iBAAiBA;gBAC5BA,MAAMA,EAAEA,GAAGA;gBACXA,GAAGA,EAAEA,KAAKA;gBACVA,IAAIA,EAAEA,KAAKA,CAACA,mCAAmCA;gBAApCA,HACdA,CAACA;YAYEA,AADAA,mHAAmHA;YACnHA,IAAIA,CAACA,QAAQA,GAAGA,CAACA,CAACA,KAAKA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,eAAeA,EAAEA,OAAOA,CAACA,IAAIA,IAAIA,CAACA,eAAeA,CAACA;YAC/EA,IAAIA,CAACA,OAAOA,GAAGA,MAAMA,IAAIA,IAAIA,CAACA;YAC9BA,IAAIA,CAACA,OAAOA,GAAGA,MAAMA,CAACA;YAEtBA,EAAEA,CAAAA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,CAAAA,CAACA;gBACbA,IAAIA,CAACA,QAAQA,GAAGA,IAAIA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,OAAOA,EAAEA,IAAIA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,CAACA;YAC1DA,CAACA;QACLA,CAACA;QAEDD;;;;;;WAMGA;QACIA,sBAAIA,GAAXA,UAAYA,MAAYA,EAAEA,MAAyBA;YAAzBE,sBAAyBA,GAAzBA,iBAAyBA;YAC/CA,EAAEA,CAAAA,CAACA,MAAMA,CAACA,CAAAA,CAACA;gBACPA,IAAIA,OAAOA,GAAiBA,IAAIA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,iBAAiBA,EAAEA,CAACA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,QAAQA,CAACA,CAACA,IAAIA,EAAEA,CAACA;gBAGjFA,AADAA,qDAAqDA;gBACrDA,EAAEA,CAAAA,CAACA,MAAMA,CAACA,MAAMA,CAACA,CAACA,CAAAA,CAACA;oBACfA,MAAMA,CAACA,MAAMA,CAACA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,EAAEA,CAACA,CAACA;gBAC/BA,CAACA;gBAAAA,IAAIA,CAACA,EAAEA,CAAAA,CAACA,MAAMA,CAACA,QAAQA,CAACA,CAACA,CAAAA,CAACA;oBAEvBA,AADAA,mBAAmBA;oBACnBA,MAAMA,CAACA,QAAQA,CAACA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,EAAEA,CAACA,CAACA;gBACjCA,CAACA;gBAAAA,IAAIA,CAAAA,CAACA;oBAEFA,AADAA,gCAAgCA;oBAChCA,MAAMA,CAACA,aAAaA,CAACA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,EAAEA,CAACA,CAACA;gBACtCA,CAACA;gBAEDA,GAAGA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,kCAAkCA,CAACA,CAACA;gBAE7CA,MAAMA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA;YACnBA,CAACA;YAAAA,IAAIA,CAAAA,CAACA;gBACFA,GAAGA,CAACA,KAAKA,CAACA,0BAA0BA,CAACA,CAAAA;YACzCA,CAACA;YAEDA,MAAMA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA;QAChBA,CAACA;QAEDF;;;;WAIGA;QACIA,mCAAiBA,GAAxBA;YACIG,MAAMA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,WAAWA,CAACA;QAC5BA,CAACA;QAEDH;;wHAEgHA;QAEhHA;;;;;;;;WAQGA;QACWA,eAAOA,GAArBA,UAAsBA,OAAiBA,EAAEA,MAAqDA,EAAEA,MAAyBA;YAAnGI,uBAAiBA,GAAjBA,YAAiBA;YAAEA,sBAAqDA,GAArDA,SAAcA,CAACA,CAACA,GAAGA,GAAGA,OAAOA,CAACA,MAAMA,CAACA,eAAeA,CAACA;YAAEA,sBAAyBA,GAAzBA,iBAAyBA;YACrHA,OAAOA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,QAAQA,GAAGA,IAAIA,OAAOA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,OAAOA,EAAEA,MAAMA,EAAEA,MAAMA,CAACA,CAACA;YAExEA,MAAMA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,QAAQA,CAACA;QACpCA,CAACA;QAEDJ;;;;;;WAMGA;QACWA,YAAIA,GAAlBA,UAAmBA,QAA4CA;YAA5CK,wBAA4CA,GAA5CA,WAAoBA,OAAOA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,QAAQA;YAE3DA,AADAA,iDAAiDA;YACjDA,QAAQA,CAACA,QAAQA,CAACA,IAAIA,EAAEA,CAACA;YAEzBA,MAAMA,CAACA,QAAQA,CAACA;QACpBA,CAACA;QAEDL;;;;;;;;WAQGA;QACWA,YAAIA,GAAlBA,UAAmBA,QAA4CA,EAAEA,MAAYA,EAAEA,MAAyBA;YAArFM,wBAA4CA,GAA5CA,WAAoBA,OAAOA,CAACA,OAAOA,CAACA,QAAQA;YAAgBA,sBAAyBA,GAAzBA,iBAAyBA;YAEpGA,AADAA,qLAAqLA;YACrLA,QAAQA,CAACA,QAAQA,GAAGA,QAAQA,CAACA,IAAIA,CAACA,MAAMA,IAAIA,QAAQA,CAACA,OAAOA,EAAEA,MAAMA,CAACA,CAACA;YAEtEA,MAAMA,CAACA,QAAQA,CAACA;QACpBA,CAACA;QAELN,cAACA;IAADA,CAACA,AAnKDD,IAmKCA;IAnKYA,eAAOA,GAAPA,OAmKZA,CAAAA;AACLA,CAACA,EAjLM,OAAO,KAAP,OAAO,QAiLb"}
```

What may be confusing is that my source files are in `assets/scripts/...` but are copied by Grunt into `WebContent/scripts`. But I did this before and it worked fine so I don't understand the issue here.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is in your grunt task somewhere. How are you injecting the HTML include statements? I'm assuming this is also a grunt task.

Comment: Yes indeed! it was because of the `sourceRoot` config attribute, I just changed it to another value and it works again :) Thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: If you want to write a proper answer, i'd give you the bounty with pleasure :)

Comment: Ah great! I'm actually only used to gulp (had a similar problem with my gulp file a few weeks ago), so won't be able to write a good answer. Glad I could help! And thanks anyway for the kind gesture of a bounty! :)

Comment: Although, if you insist... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you need to change the `sourceRoot` config attribute to point to the correct path ;).

Something like:

`{"version":3,"file":"Spinner.js","sourceRoot":"/scripts/",` ...

should do it.